# Clarifying Dirichlet Process Mixture Probability Terms

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, bayesian-network, dirichlet-distribution, dirichlet-process, infinite-mixture-model

Suppose I have a Dirichlet Process Mixture model defined as follows:

$\alpha \sim G(a,b)\\
\pi|\alpha \sim \text{Dir}(\alpha)\\
z|\pi \sim \text{Cat}(\pi)\\
$

where $G$ is just a standard Gamma distribution, and

$
\mu,\Sigma \sim NIW(\beta)
$
where $NIW$ stand for Normal Inverse Wishart.

Ultimately the plate model looks like:

[image]

Upon doing some probabilistic maniuplation I arrive at the following terms I would like some clarification on: $p(z|X),p(z|X,\alpha),p(X|z)$. I am just wondering how to interpret these.

- Is $p(z|X,\alpha) = p(z|\alpha)$? It seems that $X$ is already implicitly used in the $p(z|\alpha)$ expression as the `number of terms allocated to a cluster' in the sense of the Chinese Restaurant Process, when considering $p(z|\alpha)$ by itself, so does conditioning on $X$ change anything?
- How should I interpret the expressions $p(z|X)$ and $p(X|z)$? It feels strange because $z$ just acts like a `switch' or index for this Bayes Net, so interpreting either direction of these feels strange.
- In addition, if I add a (Gamma) prior distribution over the $\alpha$ term, with a likelihood term similar to that suggested by [Escobar & West](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/df25/adb36860c1ad9edaac04b8855a2f19e79c5b.pdf) 1995 (equations 13 / 14) then is it possible to make the claim that this empirical distribution over $\alpha$ has a *regularising* effect over the amount of clusters forming (or in the cluster allocations for each point, that is $p(z_i = k | X, \beta, \alpha, z_{\lnot i}$).

Comment: Why do you have an arrow between $\mu_K$ and $\Sigma_K$ nodes?

Comment: This is common in normal inverse wishart models where the output of $\Sigma_k$ can model the variance over the $\mu_k$, see the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-inverse-Wishart_distribution

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But you draw *both* $\mu_K$ and $\Sigma_K$ from NIW. With the arrow you are implying that a draw of $\mu_K$ depends on the draw of $\Sigma_K$ -- which is not true. Hence there is no need for an arrow between the two nodes.

Comment: I am probably wrong, but I just always assumed that the arrows point in the direction of dependency, and $\mu_k$ does depend on $\Sigma_k$. Is this an incorrect understanding?

Comment: This is a minor point and not so important from the context of your question in the post. You are correct, that if you are drawing $\mu_K$ and $\Sigma_K$ separately, you would draw $\Sigma_K$ from Inverse-Wishart distribution followed by $\mu_K$ from a Normal distribution. Since you are specifying that $(\mu_K, \Sigma_K)$ are drawn from $NIW(\beta)$, you can just skip the arrow between the two to simplify the notation.

Comment: Coming back to your main question, are you familiar with the Bayesian treatment of finite Gaussian mixture models -- i.e. GMM with finite number of Gaussian components.

Comment: Yes I am quite familiar with that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's review the generative process assumed to generate data using GMM with infinite (i.e. non-fixed) number of clusters.

1. First we need to choose a cluster assignment. Using a Chinese restaurant process, we assume that there are currently $K$ clusters, but we also have a probability to assign an observation to a new cluster $K+1$. This way we do not need to fix $K$ *a priori*,

$$
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eqn1}
  P(z_i=k\mid \alpha) =
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{N_k}{N+\alpha-1} & , k \in [1, K]\\
      \frac{\alpha}{N+\alpha-1} & , k = k_{new}=K+1\\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
$$

2. Given a cluster assignment, we can generate an observation from the corresponding Gaussian with parameters: $\mathcal{N}(\mu_k, \Sigma_k)$

For clustering, we need to determine the probability of assigning an observation to a cluster, which can be done using Bayes rule as follows,

$$\tag{2}\label{eqn2}
P(\textbf{z} \mid \textbf{X}, \alpha, \beta) \propto P(\textbf{X} \mid \textbf{z}, \beta) \times P(\textbf{z} \mid \alpha)
$$

If we are doing MCMC sampling, the above equation can be written as,

$$\tag{3}\label{eqn3}
P(z_i=k \mid \textbf{z}_{-i}, \textbf{X}, \alpha, \beta) \propto P(x_i \mid \textbf{X}_{-i}, z_i=k, \textbf{z}_{-i}, \beta) \times P(z_i=k \mid \textbf{z}_{-i}, \alpha)
$$

---

### Answering your questions:

> Is $P(\textbf{z} \mid \textbf{X}, \alpha, \beta) = P(\textbf{z} \mid \alpha)$?

No they are not. $P(\textbf{z} \mid \textbf{X}, \alpha, \beta)$ is the posterior evaluated using equation $(\ref{eqn2})$ and you get $P(\textbf{z} \mid \alpha)$ by integrating out $\pi$ as follows:

$$
P(\textbf{z} \mid \alpha) = \int_{\pi}P(\textbf{z} \mid \mathbb{\pi}) \: p(\mathbb{\pi} \mid \alpha) \: d\pi
$$

> How should I interpret the expressions $P(\textbf{z} \mid \textbf{X})$ and $P(\textbf{X} \mid \textbf{z})$?

The former term is the posterior distribution $[$ i.e. which is (\ref{eqn2}) ignoring $\alpha$ and $\beta$ $]$ of assigning clusters to the data, the latter is the likelihood of the data. The posterior is calculated using the two terms:

- $P(z_i=k \mid \alpha)$ is given by equation $(\ref{eqn1})$
- $P(x_i \mid z_i=k, \beta) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_k, \Sigma_k)$

> ... then is it possible to make the claim that this empirical distribution over $\alpha$ has a *regularising* effect over the amount of clusters forming ...

Your analysis is correct, since the choice of $\alpha$ governs how many clusters will be allocated and whether the model will have a tendency to favor existing clusters or generate more clusters.

---

### References:

1. [Gibbs sampling for fitting finite and infinite Gaussian mixture models](https://www.kamperh.com/notes/kamper_bayesgmm15.pdf) - by Herman Kamper
2. [A tutorial on Bayesian nonparametric models](http://gershmanlab.webfactional.com/pubs/GershmanBlei12.pdf) - by Gershman, Blei

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Just a few follow up comments. Perhaps a misunderstanding on my part, but my original question wasn't "is $P(\textbf{z} \mid \textbf{X}) = P(\textbf{z} \mid \alpha)$", but if $P(\textbf{z} \mid \alpha, \textbf{X}) = P(\textbf{z} \mid \alpha)$". Also in the following answer you state $P(z_i=k \mid \alpha)$  and seem to suggest it is equivalent to $P(\textbf{z} \mid \textbf{X})$? Perhaps I am not filling in the gaps because you are simplifying notation, as per your previous comment on my plate model, and I get lost in some of the conditioning??

Comment: Also I am happy that we agree on the regularizing effect on the presence of $\alpha$ but would you know of any sources or references which go into more detail on this? In particular some sort of mathematical discussion demonstrating its regularising behaviour? Thank You!

Comment: @pche8701 Sorry for the confusion. I have clarified some notations

Comment: As per the comment regarding 'regularization' I am not aware of specific literature. Will let you know if I find any.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses. I'm just a little bit stuck still on the first question. I understand your idea, but when you look at equation (2) $P(\textbf{z} \mid \textbf{X}, \alpha, \beta) \propto P(\textbf{X} \mid \textbf{z}, \beta) \times P(\textbf{z} \mid \alpha)$, we see that the $\textbf{X}$ term *only* comes into play when considering the $\beta$ hyper parameter, not when $\alpha$ is involved, which goes back to the original Q "is $P(\textbf{z} \mid \alpha, \textbf{X}) = P(\textbf{z} \mid \alpha)$", since as your posterior suggests $\textbf{X}$ only effects $\beta$ and not $\alpha$.

Comment: The main random variables governing the equations are $\textbf{z}$ and $\textbf{X}$, whereas $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the hyper-parameters. When making $\textbf{X}$ as the conditioned variable as in $p(\textbf{z} \mid \textbf{X})$, if you ought to include the hyper-parameters -- you must include both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. You cannot leave out $\beta$ as in $p(\textbf{z} \mid \textbf{X}, \alpha)$, because $\textbf{X}$ is incomplete without $\beta$.